# NameError when bypassing mass assignment while updating a user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

I followed the [Railscast tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/237-dynamic-attr-accessible?view=asciicast) for bypassing mass assignment to edit my `role` attribute of my `User` model as the `"admin"`. This is how I defined my roles:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :remember_me
  attr_accessor :accessible
  devise :database_authenticatable, ....etc
  before_create :setup_default_role_for_new_users

  ROLES = %w[admin default banned]

  private

  def setup_default_role_for_new_users
    if self.role.blank?
      self.role = "default"
    end
  end

  def mass_assignment_authorizer
    super + (accessible || [])
  end
end
```

And then I created a new  `UsersController` only to have issues with my update method:

```
def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.accessible = [:role] if user.role == "admin"
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      redirect_to @user, :notice  => "Successfully updated user."
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
end
```

I can't do this though becuase this line: `if user.role == "admin"`, is causing issue, giving me the error:

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `user' for UsersController
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `... if @user.role == "admin"`?

Comment: @KL-7 I tried that but it didn't update the `role`. If I have no `if` statment though it will update the role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `user` part in `user.role == "admin"` you're trying to use a local variable, which hasn't been defined in your `update` method. If `user` isn't declared as a helper method that's accessible in your controllers then ruby won't find it.

From your code I'm assuming that only an admin user can update the role of another user? Thus you're not using `@user.role == "admin"` but `user.role == "admin"`?

If so you have to provide a `user` object whether it's through a helper method (i.e. in your ApplicationHelper class) or fetch it before you try to use it in your update method, or with a before_* callback in your controller.

I hope it's clear what I meant.

Comment: Yes you're correct, I need it to be a helper method because doing `@user.role` does not change the role. How do I define it in the helper?

Comment: Well I'd suggest to rename the helper method to `current_user` since that's what it is. And in your ApplicationHelper class you simply have to return the user object which is your current user, which depends on your application setup... What kind of authentication/authorization do you use? Are you using any gem/plugin for that or did you write your own logic?

Comment: Well then you don't have to define this method on your own but simply write `if current_user.role == "admin"`, since Devise provides you with this method, of course only if you didn't rename it on your own.

Comment: I didn't understand the usage of `current_user` but this clarifies more. Thanks, you were correct.

Comment: `current_user` is just a simple method that returns the user object of your current user. And you don't have to write it on your own cause it's provided to you by Devise. In case of Devise, your current_user is fetched from the database by the login data in the cookies - if you didn't change this. So what it basically does is: Get the user ID of your login through cookies; Fetch the user with this ID from the database. See Devise's [README](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/)

Comment: Thanks Vapire, appreciate it.